# Lua: Convert PCRE into Lua

Tags: lua, pcre

I understand Lua does not have PCRE. How can I convert this into Lua?

```
# Quote shell chars
$a =~ s/[\002-\011\013-\032\\\#\?\`\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\*\<\=\>\~\|\; \"\!\$\&\'\202-\377]/\\$&/go;
# quote newline as '\n'                                                                             
$a =~ s/[\n]/'\n'/go;
```

Is there a general converter that can convert any PCRE into Lua?

Comment: Could you explain what you need it for? Note that Lua patterns are escaped with `%`, not with ``\``. Also, this is a Perl code snippet, it is not PCRE.

Comment: I need it to quote a string in VLC for os.execute. The string can contain any char except \0 and should not be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Please see http://ideone.com/vPyyfy. If it works as expected, please let know.

Comment: Looks good. Make it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
local a = "\002\003\004\005\006\007\008\009\010\011\012\\\n"
res, _ = a:gsub("([\002-\009\011-\026\\#?`(){}%[%]^*<>=~|; \"!$&'\130-\255])", "\\%1")
res, _ = res:gsub("\n", "'\n'")
print(res)
```

See [Lua code demo](http://ideone.com/vPyyfy)

Note that in Lua patterns, `\` is not a special char, `%` is used to replace special chars (like `[`) and `\ddd` escapes reference the decimal, not octal codes.

Comment: `res:gsub("\n", "'\\n'")` should be instead of `res:gsub("\n", "'\n'")`

Comment: If the replacement should contain ``\`` followed with `n`, then yes.